# Python lxml XPath : preceding keyword does not give expected result

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

i am trying to parse an xml document as follows

```
import re
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring

inString = """
<doc>

<q></q>

<p1>
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>1</p3>
        <p3>2</p3>
        <p3>ABC</p3>
        <p3>3</p3>

     </p2>

     <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>4</p3>
        <p3>5</p3>
        <p3>ABC</p3>
        <p3>6</p3>

     </p2>

</p1>
<r></r>
<p1>
    <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>7</p3>
        <p3>8</p3>
        <p3>ABC</p3>
        <p3>9</p3>

     </p2>

     <p2 dd="ert" ji="pp">

        <p3>10</p3>
        <p3>11</p3>
        <p3>ABC</p3>
        <p3>12</p3>

     </p2>

</p1>
</doc>
"""
root = fromstring(inString)

nodes = root.xpath("./doc//p1/p2/p3[contains(text(),'ABC')]//preceding::p2//p3")

print " ".join([re.sub('[\s+]', ' ', para.text.encode('utf-8').strip()) for para in nodes])
```

so, for each `<p1>` tag, i want to get to `<p3>` tags inside `<p2>`. Then i only want the `<p3>` tags upto tag having text like `ABC`. however, if i run the above code, i get

```
1 2 ABC 3 4 5 ABC 6 7 8 ABC 9
```

desired output is

```
1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11
```

also, if i make this change

```
nodes = root.xpath("./doc//p1/p2/p3[contains(text(),'ABC')]")
```

i get

```
ABC ABC ABC ABC
```

so looks like the second approach is able to get all the `<p3>` nodes from the entire document as per the xpath, which is fine. why doesn't my first query work?

how do i get the desired output?

Comment: Btw, why are you using `lxml.html` for the XML data? Why not `lxml.etree`?

Comment: i wanted to use the soupparser to utilize beautiful soup's html parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've located the `p3` containing `ABC`, you don't need to get up the tree - just go "sideways" using the [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling):

```
./doc//p1/p2/p3[contains(text(),'ABC')]/preceding-sibling::p3
```

Prints `1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11`.

Comment: perfect! thanks :) by the way, why just one / before preceding?

Comment: @AbtPst I am not sure, but I think `/` or `//` before the preceding-sibling would not make any difference.. Thanks.

Comment: [// is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) so `-or-self` part will get you the same results here, as there are no `p3` children the `descendant` part of `//` will not select anything